# 2D rigid body physics using runge kutta

Tags: c++, physics, runge-kutta

Does anyone know any c++/opengl sourcecode demos for 2D rigid body physics using runge kutta?

I want to build a physics engine but I need some reference code to understand better how others have implemented this.

Comment: Start with a simpler Euler method version. Once you have this, it should be easy to "upgrade" to Runge-Kutta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of things you have to take care to do this nicely. I will focus on the integrator implementation and what I have found works good for me.

For all the degrees of freedom in your system implement a function to return the accelerations `a` as a function of time `t`, positions `x` and velocities `v`. This should operate on arrays or vectors of quantities and not just scalars.

```
a = accel(t,x,v);
```

After each `RK` step evaluate the acceleration to be ready for the next step. In the loop then do this:

```
{
   // assume t,x[],v[], a[] are known
   // step time t -> t+h and calc new values
   float h2=h/2;
   vec q1 = v + h2*a;
   vec k1 = accel(t+h2, x+h2*v, q1);
   vec q2 = v + h2*k1;
   vec k2 = accel(t+h2, x+h2*q1, q2);
   vec q3 = v + h*k2;
   vec k3 = accel(t_h, x+h*q2, q3);
   float h6 = h/6;
   t = t + h;
   x = x + h*(v+h6*(a+k1+k2));
   v = v + h6*(a+2*k1+2*k2+k3);
   a = accel(t,x,v);
}
```

Why? Well the standard `RK` method requires you to make a `2xN` state vector, but the derivatives of the fist `N` elements are equal to the last `N` elements. If you split the problem up to two `N` state vectors and simplify a little you will arrive at the above scheme for 2nd order `RK`.

I have done this and the results are identical to commercial software for a plan system with `N=6` degrees of freedom.